# Can you return different values for multiple rows on the same join?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have two tables:

Parent Information

Child Information

both are structured (almost) the same with a few nuances.

The table structures are as follows:

### Parent

```
ID   |   First   |   Last   |   DOB       |   Address
-------------------------------------------------
1    |   John    |   Doe    | 1980-01-01  |   123 street
```

### Dependents

```
ParentID   |    Type   |    First   |   Last    |    DOB
--------------------------------------------------
1    |   Spouse  |    Jane    |    Doe    |   1981-02-01
1    |   Child   |    Mike    |    Doe    |   1999-08-01
1    |   Child   |    Zoe     |    Doe    |   2002-04-01
```

I want to build a query (ideally single call with joins which returns the following:

### Table Results

```
First   |    Last    |    Type    |    DOB        |     Address
---------------------------------------------------------------- 
John    |    Doe     |    Parent  |  1980-01-01   |   123 Street
Jane    |    Doe     |    Spouse  |  1981-02-01   |   123 Street
Mike    |    Doe     |   Child    |  1999-08-01   |   123 street
Zoe     |    Doe     |   Child    |  2002-04-01   |   123 Street
```

I suppose I could build the originally subquery with a LEFT JOIN on the dependents table (not all parents have dependents) then run a primary query which filters that table, however - when i do this, the query takes over a full minute to produce. (my tables change hundreds of times a day so keeping an index of the tables is not really an option as I'd have to rebuild constantly).

### UPDATE

The more I think about it even the left join would not work necessarily because the parent information and first set of dependent information would reside on the same row from the subquery (and in turn make it 'impossible' for the primary query to filter the single row into multiple).

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the joining field between Parents and Dependents?  I would expect to see a ParentID field in Dependents.....and I'm pretty sure indexes rebuild themselves, you don't have to rebuild them yourself.

Comment: @Bobby - i mention a left join in my answer - regardless, a left join would also return the result set from the first record duplicated hundreds of times - not what I want

Comment: @Leslie - sorry I had the fields marked wrong, the dependents are mapped to a parent with the parents primary ID - also - it is my understanding the index does not rebuild itself from everything I have seen. I don't necessarily want an index rebuild occurring each time there is a modification to a table with 20,000 records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t.First, t.Last, t.Type, t.DOB, t.Address
    FROM (SELECT ID, First, Last, 'Parent' as Type, DOB, Address, 1 as SortKey
             FROM Parent
          UNION ALL
          SELECT p.ID, d.First, d.Last, d.Type, d.DOB, p.Address, 
                 CASE WHEN d.Type = 'Spouse' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END as SortKey
              FROM Dependents d
                  INNER JOIN Parent p
                      ON d.ParentID = p.ID) t
    ORDER BY t.ID, t.SortKey
```

Comment: thanks for your help - I should have remembered a union but appreciate your assistance

Comment: could you use the same format to implement a 'counter' rule to the result set? (parent is always 1, spouse (if exists) is always 2, child (if exists) will grow until there are no more records for that particular parent (3,4,5,6...)